# Call HTML from PHP?

Tags: php, html, icons

I've been making a web-based app in html & PHP and have being using some font awesome icons (Really cool; http://fontawesome.io/icons/). I have placed the following in the html head of each page using these icons:

```
<div align="left"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and then the following inside the html where I want the icons:

```
<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

The problem i'm having is how would it be possible to call these from php? specifically i'm wanting it on a link button - i've tried closing and opening the php tags but it does not work as wanted.

Any help appriciated!

Comment: I messed up the post..

Comment: 4 spaces in front of each line of code formats code as code

Comment: Call what from PHP? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: The `<link.....` code need to be inside your `<head>` tag, not in the `<body>`

Comment: HTML is a language, not a process. You write a document (which could be static or dinamic in HTML), you do not "call" HTML but a webserver...

Comment: You activate a link, and what do you want to happen exactly?

Comment: Show us your PHP code what you have so far.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include stylesheets only in your `head` section. The line below suggests you included it somewhere in the `body`, in a `div element:

```
<div align="left"><link rel="stylesheet"
```

Here is some PHP code below, where I am trying to show different ways to embed PHP and HTML using various techniques (`<?php ?>`, `<?= ?>`, `echo`):

```
<?php
// display all errors, warnings, notices
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$testVar = 'This is my test page'

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title><?php echo $testVar ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?= $testVar ?></h1>

    <a class="" href="#">
        <button><i class="fa fa-cog" title="Settings"></i>Settings</button>
    </a>

    <?php echo '<a class="" href="#">
            <button><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></i>Delete</button>
        </a>'; 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy/paste all of the above code in a `.php` file and play with it, and ask if anything is not clear.

Comment: Working now thanks too this, thanks a lot it's much appreciated!

Comment: it doesn't let me as i'm new - have to get a reputation of 15 first.. whatever that means!

Comment: You might want to read more on this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179758/why-cant-i-at-least-upvote-and-comment-on-correct-and-helpful-answers-without-f and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote